# How to know custom coded language

Tags: application

How to know which custom coded language(c,c++,java) has been used in a application which is running in a production server or any server where only binary/executable files are there ?

Comment: What is a "custom coded language"?

Answer (score 1):

Java, Python, Perl, PHP, Ruby, etc. are

> script languages (except [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441824/java-virtual-machine-vs-python-interpreter-parlance))

they all depend on a interpreter (to keep it simple).

```
# ps aux
```

Will give you a list of running processes. Whenever you find `python`, `java` etc. you know what type of program/script it is.

C/C++, assembler, go etc. are

> compiler languages

Sourcecode is beeing compiled to a binary.

AFAIK you'd need [reverse engineering tools & knowledge](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/reverse-engineering-tools) to tell the difference between compiled binaries.

Here is another SO link about [Compiled vs. Interpreted Languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265357/compiled-vs-interpreted-languages)

Comment: I would not say that Java is a script language. It rather runs on its own virtual machine which allows to distinguish it from usual binaries. But it's still compiled.

Comment: True. I updated my answer.

Comment: Eh? It still says "scripted languages (except Java)"